# C# Regex Pattern Conundrum

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regex that I've verified in 3 separate sources as successfully matching the desired text.

1. http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx
2. http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx,
3. http://sourceforge.net/projects/regextester/

But, when I use the regex in my code.  It does not produce a match.  I have used other regex with this code and they have resulted in the desired matches.  I'm at a loss...

```
string SampleText = "starttexthere\r\nothertexthereendtexthere";
string RegexPattern = "(?<=starttexthere)(.*?)(?=endtexthere)";
Regex FindRegex = new Regex(@RegexPattern);
Match m = FindRegex.Match(SampleText);
```

I don't know if the problem is my regex, or my code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that your text contains a `\r\n` which means it is split across two lines. If you want to match the whole string you have to set the [option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx) to match across multiple lines, and to change the behavior of the `.` to include the `\n` (new-line character) in matched

```
 Regex FindRegex = new Regex(@RegexPattern, RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Comment: Tried that already.
Regex.Match(SampleText, @RegexPattern, RegexOptions.Multiline).Groups[1].Value.ToString() 

returns an empty string

Comment: what if you include the RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Singleline as well

Comment: Thanks Miky!  It needed both Multiline and Singleline.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `RegexOptions.Multiline`.

The problem in your case is that the dot matches any character except line break characters (`\r\` and `\n`).

So, you'll need to define your regex pattern like so: `(?<=starttexthere)[\w\r\n]+(?=endtexthere)` in order to specifically match text across line breaks.

Here's an online running sample: http://ideone.com/ZXgKar

Comment: @s15199d yes, it *does* match. Also, the code in the ideone link works.